# Accessing Loopback config data from middleware

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

Say we are in Loopback middleware, such as

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){

    // I am not sure what key to use here in the getter...
    const config = app.get('?');

});
```

I want to access the overall config that Loopback is using.

I tried:

```
const config = app.get('config');
const config = app.get('env');
const config = app.get('datasources');
```

nothing gives me quite what I want.

Interestingly, this gives me:

```
console.log(app.get('restApiRoot'));
=> '/api'
```

so that's a clue to what's going on, but I want to get the parent object(s) for the above data.

how can we access the configuration that Loopback has loaded. The configuration of course varies by environment variables etc.

I want to log what datasources.x.js file was loaded and what config.x.js file was loaded, and any other server configuration info I can capture.

Having a lot of trouble figuring out how to do this.

This seems to be the same question I have:
https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/1526

but they point me to the void that is Google Groups and I searched through there and couldn't find what the answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is actually inherited from [Express](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.get).

The entire config is stored in the `app.settings` object, with `app.get(key)` and `app.set(key,value)` just acting as getter/setter.

Doing `console.log(app.settings);` (in `server/server.js` for instance) it on a fresh loopback install returns the following:

```
{ 'x-powered-by': true,
  etag: 'weak',
  'etag fn': [Function: wetag],
  env: 'development',
  'query parser': 'extended',
  'query parser fn': [Function: parseExtendedQueryString],
  'subdomain offset': 2,
  'trust proxy': false,
  'trust proxy fn': [Function: trustNone],
  view: [Function: View],
  views: 'C:\\Users\\*******\\Documents\\GitHub\\lbtest\\views',
  'jsonp callback name': 'callback',
  host: '0.0.0.0',
  port: 3000,
  restApiRoot: '/api',
  remoting:
   { context: { enableHttpContext: false },
     rest: { normalizeHttpPath: false, xml: false },
     json: { strict: false, limit: '100kb' },
     urlencoded: { extended: true, limit: '100kb' },
     cors: false,
     errorHandler: { disableStackTrace: false } },
  legacyExplorer: false,
  'loopback-component-explorer': { mountPath: '/explorer' },
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/' }
```

Comment: yes but these files are loaded into memory in the server during boot - I want to access that, instead of re-reading the files. Plus, Loopback will choose which files to load based off of NODE_ENV etc - so for debugging purposes I want to log the config data but let Loopback do the choosing of which files get loaded, not me.

Comment: Ok, I understand better your question now. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: app.get('settings') => undefined :(

Comment: ok, so we just access app.settings directly, not app.get('settings') :)

Comment: Yes directly, like `console.log(app.settings)`. `app.get(key)` will return the value corresponding to the key in the `app.settings` object. Does this solve your problem ?